# Golang struct array not working

Tags: go

I am newbie for golang. I am trying to get user details in array.

Here is my code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type user struct {
    name  string
    email string
}

func main() {
    u := []user{}
    u[0].name = "Vanaraj"
    fmt.Println(u)
}
```

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It's working fine, but it's empty; trying to access the first element (to set its fields) fails, not because the array is not working, but because there *is no* first element.

Initialise it with elements [like this](https://play.golang.org/p/UTw-jIOU9f):

```
u := []user{user{name: "foo", email: "foo@bar.com"}}
```

Or [push new elements](https://play.golang.org/p/c9WiMY3aHf) in the array:

```
u := []user{}
newuser := user{name: "Vanaraj"}
u = append(u, newuser)
```

So that it's not empty anymore.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you're creating a slice, not an array. Go also has arrays so try not to get them mixed up.

> u[0].name = "Vanaraj"

Here you are trying to access u[0] but it doesn't exist since your slice has zero size.

You should use append, which automatically assigns a larger underlying array for your slice if needed.

```
func main() {
    u := []user{}
    u = append(u, user{name: "Vanaraj"})
    fmt.Println(u)
}
```

Alternatively you can use make when creating the slice to initialize it with some non-zero size.

```
func main() {
    u := make([]user, 1)
    u[0].name = "Vanaraj"
    fmt.Println(u)
}
```